# Network Manager - device not managed

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager

I know there are plenty of similar issues (Network Manager - device not managed) but non of proposed solutions resolves mine so far...

I've installed ubuntu server 17.10 and lubuntu-core GUI (I use LXDE one) with

```
network-manager version (1.8.4-1ubuntu3)
```

Of coure I edited `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
and changed 'managed=false' to 'managed=true' and did `sudo service network-manager restart` but nothing has changed. 
I still see:

[My Desktop nm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckk60.jpg)

My networking interfaces seen by Network Manager are as follows:

```
ela@akacja:~$ nmcli d
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
enp4s0  ethernet  unavailable  --         
enp1s0  ethernet  unmanaged    --         
lo      loopback  unmanaged    --         
ela@akacja:~$
```

Please advice what to do to manage network interfaces by lubuntu GUI.

TIA